# Not getting daily rewards on Infinite Warfare Zombies?

Tags: call-of-duty-infinite-warfare

I got a daily reward, and then went back on the next day after that and got nothing. I went on again the next day after that and still got nothing. About three days after that I finally got my daily reward. Since when do 'daily' rewards take three days to refresh? Why? I need my salvage ;_;

Answer (score 1):

I always go into the generic multiplayer to get the daily reward, didn't even know you could pick it up in zombies instead?

I'm guessing you'd have to go into zombies mode, then select multiplayer to get it to pop.

Comment: Quite strange, I got 80 salvage earlier, and a new, a few hours later, I got yet another daily reward.

Comment: They unlock at a specific time I believe (you can see a timer against the christmas items in future warfare) so if you logged on just before the timer, and then again just after you could get 2 rewards within a very short while - but then it'd be a full 24 hours before the next one.